# Move name servers from current hosting to dedicated server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nameserver, domain-name

I have a hosting and registered domain with them. I want to move to dedicated server (Ubuntu, no cpanel). In hoster panel I have ability to change nameservers IPs. Here is the response from hosting support how can I move domain:

```
Just create nameservers on your dedicated server, we can then set those to be the nameservers on your domain. This will point the domain to your server.
```

The question is: how can I create nameservers on my Ubuntu server?

Comment: I know this is not your goal, but if you only have a few domains, I do not recommend running your own nameservers.  The overhead and management is just not worth it.  Use your registrar's DNS or a 3rd party provider.  Even with dozens of servers we use DNS Made Easy to handle our DNS.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid - yeah, dnsmadeeasy has been a godsend. We centralized our DNS from half a dozen vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to chose a program to perform DNS functions, BIND and TinyDNS are two common ones. Then you need to install one of them, apt-get < your choice >. You will then need to configure them, which is beyond the scope of an answer on this site, but no shortage of tutorials exist. When the nameserver is up and running, inform your hosting provider.

Comment: What will be easier to configure -- bind or tinyDNS?

Comment: From my perspective, BIND is, but only because I have a fair bit of experience. Have a look around as Mauro suggests, you should find numerous examples of tutorials for Ubuntu..

Answer (score 1):

If you google for terms like `Bind on Ubuntu tutorial` or `MyDNS on Ubuntu tutorial` I'm sure there are tons of results that guide you through the process.